# Optimization of solve

Tags: optimization

Find the minimum value and the maximum value of the function $$y(x)=\frac{x^3}{x-3}$$ when $4\le x\le5$

I found that $f(x)$ is decreasing on the interval $[4,\frac{9}{2}]$ and increasing on $[\frac{9}{2},5]$
What i actually want is, find way to solve problem by original way, with something like simple formulas and deduction, Could someone show it?

when $4\le x\le5$

I tried to give numerator +27-27 and cut fraction and try to find min from quadratic equation, but i cannt achive something, probably its bad way

Comment: Do you mean with algebraic manipulation, with no derivatives?

Comment: Thats an exactly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find the minimum we can do the following:
$$\frac{x^3}{x-3}-m=\frac{x^3-mx+3m}{x-3}$$
and now our goal is to find $m$ such that the numerator has a double root. That is,
$$x^3-mx+3m=(x-a)^2(x-b)$$

This yields the system:
$$b=-2a$$
$$a^2+2ab=-m$$
$$a^2b=-3m$$
We find that $a=\frac92$, $b=-9$ and $m=\frac{243}4$.